# Maven Release Plugin - Managing Multi-branch Deployments to Nexus

Tags: maven

We are using the maven release plugin alongside `mvn deploy` to deploy our artifacts to Nexus via a Bamboo CICD pipeline, and manage the versions for us.

`mvn -B clean deploy release:clean release:prepare release:perform`

It works fine for our `main` branch, but when we run the same command for multiple branches (as it's in the same Bamboo build plan), it ends up in conflicts when deploying to Nexus (our Nexus disables overwriting of existing assets).

For example:

main - v1.0.1-SNAPSHOT -> When built via Bamboo and it'll deploy a v1.0.1 release into Nexus, alongside the SNAPSHOT version. It will then bump the version to v1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.

When we then create a branch from this, and run the build plan, it will generate a v1.0.2 release and the equivalent SNAPSHOT version, as expected. The problem starts arising when I have another branch from the main (v1.0.1-SNAPSHOT) that another developer is working. When the developer runs the build for their own branch, it will clash with the other dev's branch's build as there's already a v1.0.2 version in Nexus.

We tried appending the branch name onto the version to avoid conflicts (via the set:versions plugin) but the release plugin fails due to having a local commit (as per the changes made by the set:versions plugin).

The dirty workaround we have at the moment is that the second developer would need to manually update the version to the next 'available' version.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: It does not make sense to build release versions on feature branches. Release versions should be build on main/master or on stable-Branches that you need to manage bugfixes in older releases.

Comment: Hi, I agree wholeheartedly. In this case, does the release plugin then not apply to branches? I'll need to find a way in Bamboo to do a different behaviour for branches as it inherits the same CI tasks as the main.

Comment: Usually, on branches you just build a SNAPSHOT to check everything is all right, but you do not deploy it anywhere, so something like `mvn clean verify` will do.